# Indexing every WHERE column?

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning, warning

I tried to turn on `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT` and now MySQL tells me:

> No index used in query/prepared statement...

in some of my app's queries.

Is it really best practice to index every `WHERE` column I'll possibly use so that MySQL will not complain? Seems a bit overkill to me as there are probably some columns where I'll only use the `WHERE`clause occasionally.

Comment: Well, a query can only use one index at a time, so it's definitely overkill.  If you have a query where only the arguments change (but not the columns filtered on) then creating an index on those columns may be beneficial, depending on a host of factors.  But build your query(ies) first, then build index(es) to support them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on those flags only for initial development.  They are too noisy with false alarms otherwise.

There are valid cases for queries that do not use indexes.

There are cases (such as EAV) where it is impractical to have indexes for every possible query.

I prefer to turn on the slowlog with a low value for `long_query_time`, and later gather what queries are the "worst".  This is a much better list of queries to work on improving.  It may include some slow queries with the best possible index, and exclude some very fast queries that don't involve any index.

Do *not* blindly index every column.  Learn about "composite" indexes.

See [*my Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on creating optimal indexes for basic queries.

Comment: And see your other [_Question_](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/241219/no-index-used-warning-in-where-column-is-null) .