# No index used warning in WHERE column IS NULL

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, index-tuning

I'm getting this warning:

> No index used in query/prepared statement SELECT * FROM mTable WHERE my_column IS NULL

But the `my_column` is already indexed.

```
MariaDB [mytest]> SHOW INDEX FROM mTable;
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name  | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| mTable |          0 | PRIMARY   |            1 | id          | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| mTable |          1 | my_column |            1 | my_column   | A         |          11 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+-----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

Reason maybe is `my_column` actually contains `NULL` values so there's literally no index that's why MySQL complains? But then I have to query columns that are `NULL`.

Any ideas for a better approach on this?

Comment: "there's literally no index" disagrees with the `SHOW` you provide.

Comment: @RickJames What I mean is there's no actual index internally yet since most records are null, but then I don't know what's actually going on inside.

Comment: For an `INDEX`, `NULL` is a value.  There as many 'rows' in an index as there are rows in the data, regardless of whether some (or all) of the values are `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

And that is a reason why you should take the "no index used" warning with a grain of salt.

When you say one of these with `INDEX(col)`:

```
WHERE col IS NULL
WHERE col = 123
```

and the test is true more than *about* 20% of the rows in the table, the Optimizer will eschew the index and simply scan the table.

Why?  When using an index, there is a back-and-forth action between scanning the index and looking up the row in the data.  Those are two separate BTrees.  The Optimizer makes a guess as to whether it would be faster to do the back-and-forth versus simply scanning all the rows, tossing those that fail the test.

The cutoff is often around 20%, but I have see anywhere from 10% to 30%.

Answer (score 0):

You should create and index anyway.

Run the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) rowcount,my_column FROM mTable GROUP BY my_column
UNION SELECT COUNT(1) rowcount,'Whole Table' FROM mTable;
SELECT DISTINCT my_column 'Cardinality' from mTable;
```

If the number of rowcount for `NULL` is more than 5% of `Whole Table`, an index might not be used be the Query Optimizer if your `WHERE` clause is `AND my_column IS NULL` or `AND my_column IS NOT NULL` (especially if the number of rows with `NULL` is about the same as the number of rows with non-`NULL`). If the cardinality of `my_column` is very low (indicating a small number of unique values) an index on `my_column` may never be be used at all.

That warning you mentioned may go away if you create the index on `my_column`, but the index may never be used if the circumstances I mentioned apply.

The index may be of value if `NULL` my_column is like 90% of the table.

My recommendation is not to make one at this time.